# Executing installers from all the assemblies in the application

Tags: asp.net, castle-windsor, integration-testing

I'm trying to create an `IWindsorContainer` factory that executes all the installers packaged with the application (i.e. everything in the `bin` folder)

It needs to work for:

1. A Windows client application (that might or might not be installed with Clickonce)
2. A Windows service
3. A NUnit-based integration test suite (that might be run with R# while developing)
4. An ASP.NET MVC application

`FromAssembly.InThisApplication()` will not work, as this is not the "root" assembly (there might not even *be* a root assemly)

My first, naïve implementation was:

```
return new WindsorContainer()
           .Install(
               FromAssembly.InDirectory(
                    new AssemblyFilter(
                        Path.GetDirectoryName(
                            Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                                    .Location))));
```

This worked fine for 1 and 2, but not the rest.

Then I tried with:

```
return new WindsorContainer()
           .Install(
               FromAssembly.InDirectory(
                    new AssemblyFilter(
                        Path.GetDirectoryName(
                            new Uri(
                                Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                                        .CodeBase)
                                .LocalPath))));
```

Which works at least for ASP.NET, but will likely break shadow copying.

Do I have a better alternative that supports shadow copy scenarios?

Or should I forget the whole idea and run `Install(FromAssembly.InThisApplication())` from the entry point assembly, making sure all the references are explicit?

---

Additional information:

This code is part of `MyCompany.DI`, a library shared by different project types that contains... well, DI related stuff, installers for things that are used everywhere (`GenericFactoryInstaller`, for example), etc.

Other installers are contained in specific root projects, or libraries (for example, `MyCompany.Data` contains a `NHInstaller` that finds a method returning the NH configuration as uses it to create the session factory)

Put another way, this "meta-installer" should find all the installers *in the current application* and run them. I'm just trying to find a way to avoid copy&paste.

Comment: where does this code live? Why do you insist in sharing that code between all those applications? You most likely do not even want the same installers between a Windows services and a web application. Installers are meant to be application specific

Comment: @KrzysztofKoźmic I was hoping you'd chime in :-) See added info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up removing the automatic installer, and instead created the following extension method:

```
public static IWindsorContainer InstallFromAssemblies(
    this IWindsorContainer container, params string[] assemblyNames)
{
    return container.Install(assemblyNames.Select(
        x => (IWindsorInstaller)new AssemblyInstaller(Assembly.Load(x),
                                                      new InstallerFactory()))
                                          .ToArray());
}
```

So my Application-type specific code is now something like:

```
... = new WindsorContainer().InstallFromAssemblies("A.Reusable.Lib",
                                                   "My.Foo.Services",
                                                   "The.ViewModels",
                                                   "Whatever");
```